# Multiple Animated Transitions in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a nested UIStackView that holds UIImageViews.  I want each UIImageView to flip to progressively reveal a single large UIImageView.  My code shows the single view, but there is no animation to it...it just shows up immediately.  I can't figure out why there isn't a cascading effect over a few seconds.

newImage is the full screen image.

imageArray is the randomized array of smaller images that should be flipping to disappear.

```
private func flipImage(newImage: UIImage, imageArray: [UIImageView]) {
    let randomImage = imageArray.first!
    let absCoordinates = randomImage.convert(self.view.frame, to: super.view)
    let absFrame = CGRect(x: absCoordinates.origin.x, y: absCoordinates.origin.y, width: randomImage.frame.width, height: randomImage.frame.height)
    if let croppedImage = newImage.cgImage?.cropping(to: absFrame) {
        let croppedImageView = UIImageView(frame: absFrame)
        croppedImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: croppedImage)
        croppedImageView.isHidden = true
        self.view.addSubview(croppedImageView)

        let transitionOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromTop, .showHideTransitionViews]
        UIView.transition(with: croppedImageView, duration: 1, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
            croppedImageView.isHidden = false
            if imageArray.count > 1 {
                var newArr = imageArray
                newArr.removeFirst()
                self.flipImage(newImage: newImage, imageArray: newArr)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to call your

```
self.flipImage(newImage: newImage, imageArray: newArr)
```

In the completion of the transition like so:

```
UIView.transition(with: croppedImageView, duration: 1, options: transitionOptions, 
    animations: {
        croppedImageView.isHidden = false
    }, completion { _ in 
        if imageArray.count > 1 {
            var newArr = imageArray
            newArr.removeFirst()
            self.flipImage(newImage: newImage, imageArray: newArr)
        }
    }
)
```

This will flip the next Image after the first is done.

If you dont want to wait until the transition is done you can add a delay before you call the next image flip:

```
UIView.transition(with: croppedImageView, duration: 1, options: transitionOptions, 
    animations: {
        croppedImageView.isHidden = false
        if imageArray.count > 1 {
            var newArr = imageArray
            newArr.removeFirst()
            self.perform(#selector(self.flip(_:)), with: [newImage, newArr], afterDelay: 0.5)
        }
    }
)

func flip(_ data: Array<Any>) {
    self.flipImage(newImage: data[0], imageArray: data[1]) // This will probably give some errors and needs some "as! Something" 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the completion hint!  That gets the staggered timing effect, but the animation still isn't animating.  Each block is appearing rather than animating.  Any ideas?  I think it might have to do with cropping and frame size.

Comment: It was a frame/bounds issue.  I declared them after adding to view and animations are working now.   Thanks.

Comment: Great you figured it out yourself!